# Plotting the expression in 2D form

Tags: plotting

I'm plotting this function.

`Plot[rs + ts+ s, {r == 2},{t==3} {s, 2, 5}]` or

```
[{t=3, r=2}, Plot[ r s + t s + s, {s, 2, 5}]]
```

When I substitute the value of "r" in the expression then its plot graph, but for unknown "r and t" in expression and further declaration the value of "r and t", its unable to draw.

Is there any alternate method to plot the expressions with given fixed values of some variable and with given range of some other variable.

Comment: You mean something like `With[{t=3, r=2}, Plot[ r s + t s + s, {s, 2, 5}]]`?

Comment: yes sir, but its not still working  Kuba

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Do you mean you want to plot a surface? e.g. `With[{t=3}, Plot3D[ r s + t s + s, {r, 0, 2}, {s, 2, 5}]]`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange.  In order to learn how to use this site 
[take the tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour). When copying equations from a notebook to your question one should format using inline code  by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window.  It is recommended that you browse [the Markdown help](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)

Comment: Thank you so much, sir.

Answer (score 2):

If you want r and t to vary, you can try this

```
Manipulate[Plot[r s + t s + s, {s, 2, 5}], {r, 1, 4}, {t, 0, 5}]
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir, Bill Watts.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility would be to define a function that computes the expression with input arguments that include the parameters `r` and `t`.

```
f[s_, r_, t_] := r s + t s + s
```

Now when you plot it set the value of the variables, `r`=2, `t`=3.

```
Plot[f[s, 2, 3], {s, 2, 5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you so much sir, Jack LaVigne.